# What does $\mathbb{P}(X = Y) = 1$ really mean

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Does this mean $X = Y$? These are random variables. I don't get why the notation is so obtuse. I'm trying to find a joint distribution with a uniformly random variable X on [0,1] and Y defined with $\mathbb{P}(X = Y) = 1$.

My approach towards trying to find a joint distribution was to first evaluate $\mathbb{P}(X \leqslant x, Y \leqslant y_0) = \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant x \mid Y \leqslant y_0) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant y_0)$, then

$$\mathbb{P}(X \leqslant x \mid Y \leqslant y_0) = \min(x,y_0)$$ since if $y_0 > x$, we have $Y \leqslant x$ by $\mathbb{P}(Y = X) = 1$, and if it's less, then we have $X \leqslant y_0$ by the same $\mathbb{P}(Y = X) = 1$

and I got no idea what $\mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant y_0)$ is supposed to be since we aren't given a distribution for $Y$

Comment: It means that $x$ "almost surely" equals $y.$  The set of exceptions may be non-empty but has measure $0.$

Comment: $P(X\in B_1,Y\in B_2) = P(X\in B_1 \cap B_2) = \mathrm{Leb}(B_1\cap B_2)$

Comment: @Andrew What is Leb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it holds $$\mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant y_0) = \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant y_0)$$ so $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.
But why?

We have $$\mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant y_0) = \mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant y_0, X=Y) $$ due to the fact that $\mathbb{P}(X = Y) = 1$.
But on the set $\{Y \leqslant y_0, X=Y\}$ both conditions hold so we can interchange $X$ and $Y$, hence $$\{Y \leqslant y_0, X=Y\} = \{X \leqslant y_0, X=Y\}$$ and with the same argument as above we get in total:
$$\mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant y_0) = \mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant y_0, X=Y) = \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant y_0, X=Y)= \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant y_0)$$

Comment: So then, $P(X \leqslant x, Y \leqslant y_0) = P(X \leqslant x, X \leqslant y_0) = \min(x,y_0)$? 

But the only issue is that integrating over [0,1]^2 with function min(x,y_0) doesn't yield 1.

Comment: oh! i just realised its a cdf already! so then its just $\min(x,y)$?

Comment: Exactly. It holds $$P(X \leqslant x, Y \leqslant y_0) = P(X \leqslant x, X \leqslant y_0) = P(X \leqslant \min(x,y_0)) = \min(x,y_0)$$